# Get r/s w/s using iostat -x and Unix commands

Tags: bash, unix, iostat, system-monitoring

I am working on a system monitoring project and am wondering how to get just the Device, r/s, and w/s columns returned when running iostat -x.  Im sure Id have to use cut some how but my attempt at getting the 4th column (r/s) here: iostat -x | cut -f 4 is incorrect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
iostat -x | awk '{print $4}'
```

or

```
iostat -x | sed '1,/Device:/d' | awk '{print $4}'
```